# Update table 1 data to table 2

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, database, vb.net

I used a `SqlDataSource` with this code for updating the data

```
UPDATE [centreadmin]
SET [centreadmin].centre = [centre].centre
FROM [centre], [centreadmin]
WHERE [centreadmin].centre = [centre].oldcentre
```

But now I don't want to use `SqlDataSource`.

I tried this in .vb but without success.

```
Protected Sub BtnUpdateAdmin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnUpdateAdmin.Click
        Dim connection As New SqlConnection()
        connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Dim comd = connection.CreateCommand()

        connection.Open()
        comd.CommandText = "UPDATE [centreadmin] SET [centreadmin].centre = [centre].centre FROM [centre], [centreadmin] WHERE [centreadmin].centre = [centre].oldcentre"
        connection.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You're never executing the SQL. Include an [ExecuteNonQuery (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in there:

```
...
connection.Open()
comd.CommandText = "UPDATE [centreadmin] SET [centreadmin].centre = [centre].centre FROM [centre], [centreadmin] WHERE [centreadmin].centre = [centre].oldcentre"
comd.ExecuteNonQuery()
connection.Close()
...
```

Comment: Also note on the MSDN page the use of the `Using` statement for the connection to make sure all connections are properly closed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are missing executeNonQuery
So try below before connection.close()

```
comd.ExecuteNonQuery
```

Here is good [link](http://idealprogrammer.com/net-languages/code-samples/vbnet-sql-command-update-statement-source-code/) on how to insert and update records using command object